# lib/home.dart:2:8: Error: Not found: 'dart:html'

Tags: android, ios, flutter

I am new here and facing issues with the Android studio. I try to run main.dart (both ios and android) and get this warning message

** BUILD FAILED **

````
↳
Invalid depfile: /Users/przemek/AndroidStudioProjects/get_stared_app/.dart_tool/flutter_build/a0939d4e94e10e87373caa81ce1cf2b7/kernel_snapshot.d
Invalid depfile: /Users/przemek/AndroidStudioProjects/get_stared_app/.dart_tool/flutter_build/a0939d4e94e10e87373caa81ce1cf2b7/kernel_snapshot.d
Invalid depfile: /Users/przemek/AndroidStudioProjects/get_stared_app/.dart_tool/flutter_build/a0939d4e94e10e87373caa81ce1cf2b7/kernel_snapshot.d
Invalid depfile: /Users/przemek/AndroidStudioProjects/get_stared_app/.dart_tool/flutter_build/a0939d4e94e10e87373caa81ce1cf2b7/kernel_snapshot.d
lib/home.dart:2:8: Error: Not found: 'dart:html'
import "dart:html";
       ^
Unhandled exception:
FileSystemException(uri=org-dartlang-untranslatable-uri:dart%3Ahtml; message=StandardFileSystem only supports file:* and data:* URIs)
#0      StandardFileSystem.entityForUri (package:front_end/src/api_prototype/standard_file_system.dart:33:7)
#1      asFileUri (package:vm/kernel_front_end.dart:659:37)
#2      writeDepfile (package:vm/kernel_front_end.dart:853:21)
<asynchronous suspension>
#3      FrontendCompiler.compile (package:frontend_server/frontend_server.dart:574:15)
<asynchronous suspension>
#4      _FlutterFrontendCompiler.compile (package:flutter_frontend_server/server.dart:43:22)
#5      starter (package:flutter_frontend_server/server.dart:182:27)
#6      main (file:///b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/flutter/flutter_frontend_server/bin/starter.dart:9:30)
#7      _startIsolate.<anonymous closure> (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:299:32)
#8      _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:168:12)


Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
note: Using new build system
note: Building targets in parallel
note: Planning build
note: Constructing build description
warning: Capabilities for Signing & Capabilities may not function correctly because its entitlements use a placeholder team ID. To resolve this, select a development team in the Runner editor. (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')```

What should I do to fix it? Many thanks for the help in the advance. I updated my Andorid studio this morning and since that time I have this issue
````

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try replacing `dart:html` with `dart:io` at the top of your main.dart file.

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answer does not always help. Sometimes the use of `universal_html` is more suitable. Just install the latest package and use the import as:

```dart
import 'package:universal_html/html.dart' as html;
```

Answer (score 0):

the error can be due also to the import of these two if they are not used

```
import 'dart:html';
import 'dart:ui';
```

delete these imports and save

Answer (score -2):

Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone x86 in debug mode... Invalid depfile: C:\Users\asilswal\repo\SignIn\SignInMobile\signin.dart_tool\flutter_build\223fbab5937d75386a2faf5f5c64434e\kernel_snapshot.d Invalid depfile:

C:\Users\asilswal\repo\SignIn\SignInMobile\signin.dart_tool\flutter_build\223fbab5937d75386a2faf5f5c64434e\kernel_snapshot.d

: Error: Dart library 'dart:html' is not available on this platform. import 'dart:html';

```
   ^ Context: The unavailable library 'dart:html' is imported through these packages:

package:signin => dart:html
```

Detailed import paths for (some of) the these imports:
package:signin/main.dart => package:signin/ui/pages/login/login.dart
=> package:signin/blocs/provider.dart => package:signin/blocs/login_bloc.dart => dart:html package:signin/main.dart => package:signin/ui/pages/login/login.dart
=> package:signin/blocs/login_bloc.dart => dart:html

**#Understanding the Error:**
dart:html’ is not available on this platform
The error message indicates that the ‘dart:html’ library is being imported in your Flutter project but is not available on the platform you are trying to run the app. This occurs because ‘dart:html’ is specific to web-based applications and cannot be used on mobile platforms, such as Android or iOS.

**Root Cause:**
The ‘dart:html’ library provides APIs to interact with the browser’s Document Object Model (DOM) and other web-specific features. Since Flutter is a multi-platform framework that targets various platforms, including mobile and web, some packages may inadvertently import ‘dart:html,’ causing the error when running on non-web platforms.

**Solution:**
If you are exclusively developing an app for mobile platforms and have mistakenly imported the package ‘dart:html’ in any class, kindly remove this import statement and proceed with running your application. The ‘dart:html’ library is intended for web-based applications and is not compatible with mobile platforms. By removing this accidental import, you can avoid any compatibility issues and ensure a smooth execution of your app on mobile devices.

**flutter clean**

**flutter pub get**

**flutter run**

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).